# Are there any options for IOS development on Windows 8? (Apps, Emulators, Cloud Computing OK)

Tags: macos, development, windows

I am trying to develop iPhone apps on Windows 8. To do that, I might need an emulator to run certain IOS development programs.

I would like to know if there are any OS-X emulators available for Windows and which ones are to be recommended? Please note that I am willing to pay for the emulators (doesn't necessarily have to be free).

If emulators aren't an option, I'm also willing to use cloud-computing, provided it works.

I just came across a service called macincloud.com, which supposedly allows you to rent a Mac-OS server.

I am willing to invest in this, which costs $20/month, so I seriously need to know if this is legit or not. I am not willing to pony up money for something that's unreliable.

Please tell me your thoughts on that service.

If none of those options are possible, are there any options that allow me to develop AND preview the app using Windows without submitting the product to Apple?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not virtualize OS X?

Comment: You mean I could set up a virtual Mac-Os-X machine through Virtual Box? That would be a good option for development if they allow that. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible yes, against the eula, if that means anything foe you. Works just fine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the license for OS X, you are not allowed to run it on non-Apple hardware.

If any emulators do exist, or methods to hack existing virtualization software to run it on non-Apple hardware, that would not be legal.

Legally, you could technically buy some Apple hardware like an iMac or Mac Pro, install Windows on it, and then run virtualized OS X within Windows, but I'm not certain virtualization software that will do this exists.

The only virtualization system I know of that supports OS X is VMWare ESXi, but I believe that's a bare-metal hypervisor that won't run on Windows.

You will probably be best served by buying a Mac Mini and either KVMing it or connecting to it with VNC.

**EDIT:**

You mentioned http://www.macincloud.com -- I can't speak to the reputability of that particular business, but the premise is sound. They could be running multiple instances of OS X on ESXi hypervisor running on Mac Pro or Mac mini server hardware, or they could be renting out individual Mac mini servers -- making each instance accessible over VNC.

Here are two articles that may give some credit to MacinCloud's reliability:

- http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/03/15/corona-developers-rent-a-mac-in-the-cloud/
- http://gizmodo.com/5853926/join-a-mac-timeshare-in-the-clouds

Comment: and downloading video game emulators on OS-X is legal?

Comment: Yup. Windows and game licenses don't have hardware restrictions. You still have to buy the games, obviously.

Comment: A common developer solution is to virtualize your Windows 8 needs. Buy a Mac and run Windows in a VM or on Bootcamp partition (or both). You then have access to all OS's.

Comment: @8None1 That's what I do! VMWare Fusion with a second monitor is where it's at.

Comment: awesome! That site looks promising. I'll need to do a little more research before I decide to pull the trigger though. Will Apple let me submit applications to them if I'm using the remote server?

Comment: I don't actually know enough about the App store submission process to know for sure, but given that MacinCloud is marketed towards developers for that very reason, I would be very surprised if there were issues with that.

Comment: All VMware virtualization products (Fusion, Workstation, vSphere, and ESXi) perform checks that are specific to OS X. One is to ensure that the hardware is Apple hardware, the other is to ensure that the version of OS X that you're attempting to virtualize is a version whose EULA allows for virtualization. You could install Windows on a Mac, install Workstation on that Mac-running-Windows, and then virtualize OS X in Workstation.